# Is there a way to create an element that appears when a different element is hovered on AND follows the cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, show

## Goal

As the title says, I'm trying to have two elements, element A and element B. I want to have element B to only show when element A is hovered on, but I also want element B to follow the cursor **without jittering.**

I can get the hovering/showing part to work on it's own, and I can get the following cursor part to work on it's own, but I can't seem to put them together without using offsetX/offsetY, which causes it to jitter.

## Code

#### EDIT:

for some reason the code snippet doesn't work correctly, just copy the code into a file.

The HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="A"></div>
      <div id="B"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```css
* {
 margin: 10px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute; /* Not needed in this example, but required for what I'm trying to make, I'm adding it because it might be relevant. */
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#A {
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#B {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#A:hover~#B {
  display: block;
}
```

and the JavaScript:

```js
let b = document.getElementById('B');

const onMouseMove = (e) =>{
  b.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px';
  b.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

## Explanation

As you can see, A and B are both in the `content` div. If I move one of them out, then the hover thing stops working. However, if you try running this, you'll see that B flickers a bunch (you might need to remove `display: none` from the CSS), and 'teleports' to the top left corner. As far as I can tell (from Google), this is because I'm using offsetX/offsetY instead of pageX and pageY. I can change it to that, but since it's relative to the page, and I'm trying to set it relative to the parent element (`content` in this case), it's not at the right position and changes when you zoom, which is a big problem. The real problem here, though, is that A and B need to have the same parent element (`content`) for the hover/show CSS to work, and B needs to be outside of the `body` to work with pageX and pageY.

## Question

Is there some other method to do one of the two things I'm trying to accomplish? Is there some other method with CSS to hide/show elements which aren't in the same div? or some way with javascript? I'd prefer to not use jQuery if possible. I've tried adding an event listener for mouseover and mouseout, but they trigger incorrectly, and if I just console.log any events, mousing over makes it trigger mouseover and mouseout multiple times, which would cause it to flicker. Is there some way to get how far the edge of `content` is from the left/top of the window in pixels? if so, I could subtract that from pageX/pageY and that might work.

By the way, if there is something I'm doing that seems not necessary, or the description I'm giving isn't what happens when you try viewing the html/whatever, please let me know, though it might be because the original code was long enough I wouldn't post it here, so I tried to make an example that shows the same thing.

I'm not really sure what to do in this situation besides just ask, but as usual there is probably some simple answer I didn't think of. I tried to make this question more legible than I have in the past, so hopefully it shows. Thanks for any help in advance!

#### EDIT

I figured I might as well include the actual code I'm using for my project, in case I got something wrong in the example code, or forgot to include something I didn't realize was relevant. https://codepen.io/fun840/pen/QWprQXy

#### EDIT 2

As @DavidsaysreinstateMonica pointed out in the comments, I didn't specify what are elements A and B in my actual code (on codepen). Element A is `mainitem` and element B is `tooltip-border`.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I also don't know why it works, but as I said in the question, pageY and pageX don't flicker. the only problem is, if you zoom in/out or resize the window, it's position changes in relation to your mouse (so if you moved it the right amount to be, for example, right on the pointer, it would change when you resize the window or zoom.)

Comment: @Fun840: my apologies, I managed to miss your own experimentation with `e.pageX`/`e.pageY`. My earlier comment deleted since it's clearly pointing out the obvious at this stage. As you've linked to your real code, could you clarify in that code which elements are your "element A" and "element B"?

Comment: @pilchard 1. I think part of that is the stackoverflow code snippet being weird, try copy-pasting the code. 2. How do I detect mouse enter/leave? As I said in the question, mouseover and mouseout events are unreliable.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the post, but element A is `mainitem` and element B is `tooltip-border`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add `pointer-events: none;` to the `#B` css. It would fix it since the B will not intercept the mouse events anymore.

```js
let b = document.getElementById('B');

const onMouseMove = (e) =>{
  b.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px';
  b.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

```css
* {
 margin: 10px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute; /* Not needed in this example, but required for what I'm trying to make, I'm adding it because it might be relevant. */
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#A {
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#B {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#A:hover~#B {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="A"></div>
      <div id="B"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```